# Angular 1.4.2 injection of $cookies not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, dependency-injection

I have a problem with Angular and injecting $cookies into a controller.

The $cookies is working fine in a service, but with this controller I'm getting an issue.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    "ui.router",
    "ngCookies",
    'ui.bootstrap']);

angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("ListController", ListController);

ListController.$inject = ['$scope', 'DataService', '$state', "AuthenticationService", "$cookies"];

function ListController($scope, DataService, $state, AuthenticationService, $cookies) {
    ....
}
```

The $cookies object is coming through as **undefined**. The angular-cookies.js is included on the page, and is working inside the included AuthenticationService.

Comment: Where you pass the parms in your controller?

Comment: First you really should avoid mixing `"` and `'` quote notation. Choose one and stick to it till the end of your project. (JShint advise the use of `'`) Regarding ngCookie issue, Have you tried to declare your controller in the old fashion way first ? May I ask you to reproduce your bug in a plunker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem:

Someone had cut and pasted the original controller code into a new controller, but neglected to rename the controller on the line:

```
ListController.$inject =[...];
```

So, when I came along and added the $cookies parameter, my version was being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    "ui.router",
    "ngCookies",
    'ui.bootstrap']);

angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("ListController",['$scope', 'DataService', '$state', "AuthenticationService", "$cookies", function ($scope, DataService, $state, AuthenticationService, $cookies) {
    ....
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the file angular-cookies[.min].js ?

Also, as a good practice, don't use the same module for the app and the controllers. Have a

```
angular.module('app', [ 'app.controllers']);

angular.module('app.controllers', [
  \\ define each controller here
]);
```

defined so that you can have clean separation of them.

Comment: Yes, it's included, and as I said working in another service.

Answer (score 0):

Are $scope, DateService, $state available in your controller? I usually put this line of code after the declaration of controller

> angular
>       .module("app")
>       .controller("ListController", ListController);